# Desaturate colors around lightsource

Tags: node-editor, light, lighting

I'm still new to Blender and I just found out that lights have a nodes option and that there are many things you can do with them.

I am working on a render but I have an issue with an area with oversaturated shadows.
**I want to make a light source that desaturates the colours around it** and nothing else.

Is it possible to do and does anyone know how to do it?

Comment: Hi Chociily, I have seen your question. I am unable to understand what you want to achieve here. Can you tell it with a little more detail?

Comment: I am basically trying to make a light that turns things more grayscale the closer it is to an object.

Comment: I don't think that is possible through shader nodes.

Comment: @chocilly, do you want the shadows to be less saturated or something else has to be less saturated?

Comment: @Aster17 I wanted to make a light that I could put near a shadow (the shadow was a deep oversaturated blue) to make it less saturated. But I just found an alternative way to fix it, by forcing the material to use a certain colour of shadows. Thanks for your time though!

Comment: Sure. No problem. But next time, try to add a little more detail and try adding a bit of a picture to make it easier.

Answer (score 13):

To desaturate objects closer to a light, add 4 nodes to your object's material:

1. *Texture coordinate > Object:* target your light
2. *Vector Math > Length* - gives lower value for objects closer to that light
3. *Math > Multiply* - to control the falloff
4. *Hue/Saturation node*, to control the saturation

(You can wrap the setup in a nodegroup and put inside every material)

[image]