# Density of a volume proportional to the proximity to a surface

Tags: rendering, volumetrics

I apologize if I can't explain it correctly. What I am looking for is the following in Cycles:
Given 2 objects, one rendered as a volume (scatter or absorption) and one as a surface, I want to change the density of the volume based on the proximity to the surface object. Imagine if the volume is a UV sphere and the surface is a cube, when the cube is inside the sphere, the desnity of the sphere should be proportional to the distance of the point in the volume to the cube.
Is this achievable?
All I can do is get proximity to a face with geometry node, but not proximity to a volume

Comment: Hi :). Should be easy using this setup with volume [Desaturate colors around lightsource](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/212574/78972). Just can't make it work reliably at the moment :))

Comment: thanks for the answer! I tested the method and it seems like proximity is calculated only for 1 point, looks like it's the mesh's origin. Is it possible to get the same exact mechanism, but that it takes into account the entire surface (the mesh I am using is a human)? I am guessing maybe using geometry node proximity value?

Comment: Hi :). You're right, it uses the origin point. Not sure how to target the surface directly :)

Comment: normally it should be an easy setup with GN and it works with my shader (if you plugin my principled bsdf to surface output you can see the color changes by the distance) but...the density of my volume shader doesn't "react". I have no idea why...[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nZ0ZG.png [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hPTbv.jpg  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rH4WZ.jpg [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dzVg6.gif

Comment: Hi @Chris :). Had a similar hiccup yesterday, the multiply/add node isn't very intuitive for density. I later simply multiplied a colorramp and it worked fine https://imgur.com/a/moPKZR8

Comment: @JachymMichal: Thanks ;) but unfortunately you have input values of 0-1 and my input value can be greater than 1 so the "pure" colorramp won't work, i think. I must made a very stupid mistake...but i have no idea...or it is a bug

Comment: @Chris I think the reason the volume is not reacting is the same reason why you can't color a volume using an image texture,  the input is 2D, whereas if you use a noise texture it works cause it's 3D. So I suspect that the proximity value from the geometry node is actually 2D but I don't know how to verify it